# Is there a way to programmatically save an AngularJS page as pure HTML, with all the contents

Tags: angularjs, seo

Is there a way to save a rendered AngularJS page as HTML on the fly, and then serve it to search engine bots?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fly"? If you're talking about server-side rendering of AngularJS, that does not exist until Angular Universal in Angular 5 or above. If you just want to do an initial render of AngularJS on a web server and serve it up as a static page with all the AngularJS features stripped from it, you'd need a custom solution using NodeJS, but I can't see why anyone would want to do that. There are better solutions like Express.js's built-in templating engine.

Comment: You can return files based on the user agent (to filter bots). If it's a bot, you return the prerendered page with PhantomJS, else you return the index.html file

Comment: @JacobStamm I meant  client-side, creating a similar page as a normal user would see, and store it on the server as a cached copy to serve to GoogleBot and similar. I would like to avoid doing that manually, or keeping to separate versions of each page, one for bots and the other one for users.

Comment: @Ziad seems like PhantomJS is discontinued? Was there a way to use store the page as html as well? The obvious examples looked more like screen shots.

Comment: @Kjell If you want server-side caching, then you need server-side rendering, and AngularJS is not the tool for the job